# Refresh doesn't work before creating a war with Ant on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, file-copying

On Eclipse I create war files by using ant.

The issue is that in the war file isn't included the right `mypropfile.properties`.
The file is properly copied, but also if I use `<eclipse.refreshLocal resource="projectdir" depth="infinite"/>` the old file is included. I have to refresh manually the project.

For Ant I use the "Run in the same JRE as the workspace" option.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MyProject" basedir=".">
<description>
    My Project
</description>

<property name="workspace.dir" value="${basedir}/../../"/>
<property name="src" value="${basedir}/../src"/>
<property name="build" value="${basedir}/../build"/>
<property name="build.classes" value="${basedir}/../build/classes"/>
<property name="lib.dir" value="${basedir}/WEB-INF/lib"/>
<property name="web.dir" value="${basedir}/WEB-INF"/>
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="real.dir" value="${basedir}/real"/>
<property name="real2.dir" value="${basedir}/real2"/>

<path id="classpath.server">  
    <fileset dir="${env.CATALINA_HOME}/lib" includes="*.jar"/>  
    <pathelement path="${build.classes}"/>
</path>

<path id="classpath.app">  
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>  
</path> 

<target name="refreshResource" if="eclipse.refreshLocal">
    <eclipse.refreshLocal resource="projectdir" depth="infinite"/>
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build}/classes"/>
    <delete dir="${build}"/>
</target>

<target name="init" depends="clean, refreshResource">
    <tstamp/>
    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build}/classes"/>
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac encoding="UTF8" srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}/classes"    includeantruntime="false">
        <compilerarg value="-Xlint:unchecked"/>
        <classpath>  
            <path refid="classpath.server.bin"/>  
        </classpath>
        <classpath>  
            <path refid="classpath.server"/>  
        </classpath> 
        <classpath>
            <path refid="classpath.app"/>
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>  
         </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="deleteConfig">
    <delete file="${src}/mypropfile.properties"/>
</target>

<target name="real" depends="deleteConfig">
    <copy file="${real.dir}/realprop.properties" tofile="${src}/mypropfile.properties"/>
</target>

<target name="real2" depends="deleteConfig">
    <copy file="${real2.dir}/real2prop.properties" tofile="${src}/mypropfile.properties"/>
</target>

<target name="war-real" depends="real, compile">
    <input message="Warname (without .war):" addproperty="warname"/>
    <war destfile="${workspace.dir}/${warname}.war" webxml="${web.dir}/web.xml">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}">
            <include name="**/*.*"/>
        </fileset>
        <classes dir="${build.classes}"/>
    </war>
</target>

<target name="war-real2" depends="real2, compile">
    <input message="Warname (without .war):" addproperty="warname"/>
    <war destfile="${workspace.dir}/${warname}.war" webxml="${web.dir}/web.xml">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}">
          <include name="**/*.*"/>
        </fileset>
        <classes dir="${build.classes}"/>
    </war>
</target>
```

**EDIT**

The target clean was wrong, so I've corrected it, but now build failed with error

```
BUILD FAILED ... Reference classpath.server.bin not found.
```

Comment: Which version of Ant? How do you know that it's not the right file?

Comment: The target `clean` was wrong. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ant doesn't care if Eclipse has refreshed the file or not. `eclipse.refreshLocal` is only relevant for editors and compilers inside of the IDE.

When you run the Ant `build.xml`, Ant copies the file in question in the `real` target into the source folder and `compile` copies it into `${build}/classes` (at least it should do that). So before you create the WAR, you must make sure the `compile` step has done its work (i.e. look into each file to make sure that a change is visible in each copy).

What worries my is that you use different ways to access the `classes`:

- `${build}/classes`
- `${build.classes}`
- `${basedir}/../build/classes`

So the first step should be to define a single way to locate the folder and then use this pattern everywhere.

If that doesn't solve your problem, you need to make sure Ant notices that the file has changed. Old filesystems like FAT support only timestamps which have second resolution. If you use an USB stick for your sources, it's possible to change the file and run Ant so fast that Ant thinks the file hasn't changed.

Lastly, you need to check your classpath. If one of the JAR dependencies also contains a file called `mypropfile.properties`, then Java resource loading can find either version.

This and other problems made me use a different solution to configure WAR files: I pass a system property with the absolute path of the config file. That way, the WAR file doesn't change when the config changes and I have full control over which config file is loaded.

Comment: I have to copy the file into the source folder, 'cause a need a different uncommented part of that file according to the war type. I can't use two different files for this.

Comment: Is that what `war-real` and `war-real2` are for?

Comment: the two target have different dipendencies. Basically they copies the same file with a different part uncommented (realprop.properties or real2prop.properties). Eventually the file has the name `mypropfile.properties`

Comment: How about passing a property to the WAR which tells it what type you want? Think of it as a prefix for all keys in the `mypropfile.properties` file. That way, you wouldn't have to comment/uncomment anything.

Comment: I thought about it, but for different reasons that depend on deploy env it's not possible. I would a way to copy that file and include it in the war properly.

Comment: I understand. At which of the steps does it break? Which files are correct and how do you know?

Comment: when war target is executed, the copy is done properly, but I see it only if I refresh manually the project (the war includes the old one). So if I rerun the same war target after a manual refresh it works

Comment: What you describe looks like that Ant is taking file from Eclipse's `build` folder, maybe in addition to the ones in `${src}`. Ant shouldn't see/use files from the `build` folder (the output folder which you configured in Eclipse) since you can never know when and if Eclipse updates them. Check the paths where Ant is copying files **from** and make sure they are correct.

Comment: Also don't try to debug this problem inside of Eclipse. Look at the actual files on the hard disk, using a normal file explorer and a ZIP tool/archiver to see what is actually going on. IDEs sometimes lie to you.

Comment: for example the target clean doesn't delete the dir build which its content

Comment: How many file with the name `mypropfile.properties` are in the WAR file?

Comment: there is only one file named `mypropfile.properties`